# Esri Query, JQuery Ajax: Not Liking a Ajax Return

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, esri

I have a JQuery Ajax Call as per the following code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "spaceplanning_database.asmx/GetRoomDataAttributes",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            restricted_attributes_global = msg.d;
            console.log(msg.d);// "OBJECTID", "Room", "Floor", "OBJECTID_BLDG", "Room_GUID", "PKey", "SHAPE"
            var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://gisserver/xxx", {
                mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
            //outFields: [restricted_attributes_global], //doesn't work
            outFields: ["OBJECTID", "Room", "Floor", "OBJECTID_BLDG", "Room_GUID", "PKey", "SHAPE"],
            });

            map.addLayer(featureLayer);

        }
    });
```

Basically, this calls a C# Web Service and gets some database column names (such as OBJECTID, Room). The column names are padded in the Web Service with double quotes, per

```
string allowed_loc = "\"" + reader["COLUMN_NAME"] + "\"";
```

in a loop.

The console.log in the code above shows the output for `msg.d`; but when this assigned to the `restricted_attributes_global` variable and used in the Esri query then I see an error:

```
esri.layers.FeatureLayer: unable to find '"OBJECTID","Room","Floor","OBJECTID_BLDG","Room_GUID","PKey","SHAPE"' field in the layer 'fields'
```

But, as in the code above, I copy/paste the console.log value as hard-coded then the Esri query works. Maybe I need to put the double quotes in C# in a different way, or type charset to something else in the Ajax call? What could be happening?

I think this question falls somewhere in between JQuery, C# and Esri queries.

Comment: I think I know what is going on: The 'restricted_attributes_global ' variable needs to be an array--right now it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out in my Comment above, I had to make an array object to pass to the `outFields` variable and I just couldn't make it work with the `FeatureLayer` mode. So I ended up using a `QueryTask`. Here is relevant code:

```
...//code as above this line
restricted_attributes_global = msg.d;
var array = restricted_attributes_global.split(',');//converting to array
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://gisserver/xx");
query.where = "OBJECTID_BLDG=12";
query.outSpatialReference = { wkid: 102100 };
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = [array];// passing the array
```

QueryTask was the better route for my application anyway. The C# code is changed to remove the double quotes now:

```
allowed_attributes.Add(reader["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
```

Everything working like a charm now.

HTH.